# Installation Issues: UEFI/Win10/nVidia

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, usb, uefi

I'm having some issues getting Ubuntu to install (latest ISO as of today).
I bought a drive specifically for the purpose of using Ubuntu, its sata based, where as my data and windows drives are nvme & m.2 sata respectively.

My GPU is nvidia based.
I created the installer using Rufus 3.6 on Windows 10, on a 8Gb stick.

Whatever i do, whatever options, the installer or live CD gets to the 5 dots then just loads, no freezing, no crashing, just on & on with the dots.

Upto now, i've tried:

1. nomodeset
2. uefi fastboot = off
3. uefi secureboot = off
4. Moving from USB 3.0 ports to USB 2.0 ports
5. Every other combination i can think of.

I'm going to try creating with an 18.x image in a few mins, but any help you can suggest or give would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: When it shows the dots, can you press one of the arrow keys to show the console boot log and see what it gets stuck on?

Comment: Apologies, i was configuring my hardware in Ubuntu all afternoon. If i pressed 'F6' it failed on everything. Re-creating the USB installer as 18.x saw no further issues with installation, and didn't need me to do anything new. Similarly, a 18->19 in-place upgrade also worked fine. Perhaps coincidentally, this is a similar fault to what i saw at work, creating an Ubuntu Server install on a Gen2 Hyper-V template. Must be a UEFI related bug in the installer?

Comment: Hmm that is odd. I personally despise UEFI and always install in legacy mode. (Although some other users here will say UEFI is the best thing since sliced bread). Everyone is entitled to their own opinion :)

Comment: UEFI is the best thing since sliced bread! :) And actually mandatory for your system because NVME > NOT an opinion.